# Android rfcomm ioexception

Tags: java, android, ioexception, rfcomm

I'm trying to learn rfcomm on Android and made this Activity to help me...The problem is that I always get an IOException at the line where `***` is presented.

Here is my code :

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class BluetoothCom extends Fragment {

        private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
        private static final String TAG = "APP";
         private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        static BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        TextView bluetoothState;
        ArrayAdapter<String> bluetoothDevices;
        List<String> btDevicesList;
        List<UUID> uuids;
        ListView bluetoothDevicesAvailable;
        View v;
        Button startBluetooth, searchForDevices;

        ConnectThread mConnectThread;
        ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

        // Constants that indicate the current connection state
        public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
        public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
        public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

        int STATE = STATE_NONE;



        public BluetoothCom(Context context) {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bluetooth, container,
                    false);
            v = view;
            searchForDevices = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.bSearchDevices);
            bluetoothState = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.tvBluetoothState);
            bluetoothDevicesAvailable = (ListView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.lvBluetoothDevicesAvailable);
            configBluetooth();

            // LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)
            // inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bluetooth, container, false);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            getActivity();
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                configBluetooth();
            }
        }

        private void configBluetooth() {

            if (bluetooth != null) {
                if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
                    searchForDevices.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled");

                    searchForDevices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            searchBluetoothDevices();
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    startBluetooth = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.bActivateBluetooth);
                    startBluetooth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    startBluetooth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            bluetooth.enable();
                            bluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth has been enabled");
                            startBluetooth.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            configBluetooth();
                        }
                    });
                    bluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is Disabled.");
                }
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage(
                                "It seems that your device does not have any bluetooth adapter.")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // continue with delete
                                        getActivity().finish();
                                    }
                                }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void searchBluetoothDevices() {
            final List<BluetoothDevice> tmpBtChecker = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            bluetooth.startDiscovery();
            uuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();
            final ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                        // clearing any existing list data
                        tmpBtChecker.clear();
                    }
                    if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                        //discovery has finished
                    }
                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent
                                .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        if (!tmpBtChecker.contains(device)) {
                            tmpBtChecker.add(device);
                            ar.add(device.getName() + "    " + device.getAddress());

                        }
                        bluetoothDevicesAvailable.setAdapter(ar);
                        bluetoothDevicesAvailable.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                BluetoothDevice device = tmpBtChecker.get(position);
                                mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
                                mConnectThread.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        }
         public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {

                // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
                if (STATE == STATE_CONNECTING) {
                    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
                }

                // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
                if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

                // Start the thread to connect with the given device
                mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
                mConnectThread.start();
                STATE = STATE_CONNECTING;
            }


         public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
                // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
                if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

                // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
                if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

                // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
                mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                mConnectedThread.start();
                STATE = STATE_CONNECTED;
            }

         private void connectionLost() {
                STATE = STATE_NONE;

                // Send a failure message back to the Activity
                Toast t = new Toast(getActivity());
                t.makeText(getActivity(), "Conexiune pierduta!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

            public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
                mmDevice = device;
                BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

                // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
                // given BluetoothDevice
                try {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
                }
                mmSocket = tmp;
            }

            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
                setName("ConnectThread");

                // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
                bluetooth.cancelDiscovery();

                // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    mmSocket.connect();   //Here is the problematic line***
//HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed Connecting to the device!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Close the socket
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                    }
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    //BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    return;
                }

                // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done

                   mConnectThread = null;


                // Start the connected thread
                connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
                }
            }
        }


        private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
            private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
            private final InputStream mmInStream;
            private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

            public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
                mmSocket = socket;
                InputStream tmpIn = null;
                OutputStream tmpOut = null;

                // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
                try {
                    tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                    tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
                }

                mmInStream = tmpIn;
                mmOutStream = tmpOut;
            }

            public void run() {
                Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytes;

                // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
                while (true) {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    //bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String a = "50";
                    buffer = a.getBytes();
                    try {
                        mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * Write to the connected OutStream.
             * @param buffer  The bytes to write
             */
            public void write(byte[] buffer) {
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                    // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                    //mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothChat.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
                }
            }

            public void cancel() {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is adapted from this source : http://blog.bastelhalde.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/BluetoothChat.zip

What am I doing wrong?